# Derivation for the 1d wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, wave-equation, arc-length

So I'm working on PDEs, and currently trying to understand the derivation of the 1d wave equation.  I can follow most of this derivation just fine, but when I try it myself I run into a snag I'm not sure how to conceptually address.  In the text (PDEs by Strauss), the author uses [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKoX9.png).  This diagram is meant to demonstrate the directions of the tension force along a string, such that newton's laws can be used to derive the PDE.

The diagram shows how to determine the magnitude of the tension in both the x and u (horizontal and vertical respectively) directions.  This should just be some basic trig, and so it represents this with a triangle that has a vertical side of $u_x$ and a base of unit length (and thus the hypotenuse is given as $\sqrt{1 + u_x^2}$)

But when I try to approach this problem, without following along, I end up drawing a similar triangle, but this time I make my base a $dx$, and the vertical a $du$.  Following this through I'd find:

$\sqrt{dx^2 + du^2} = \sqrt{dx^2 + \frac{dx^2 du^2}{dx^2}} = \sqrt{dx^2 (1 + u_x^2)} = \sqrt{1 + u_x^2}dx$

(Thats just the integral form of the arc length equation, which makes sense).

What I'm doing feels conceptually correct.  I'm interested in the tension at two points arbitrarily close together (separated horizontally by $dx$ and vertically by $du$).  But that additional $dx$ in my result leaves me a bit stuck on how to proceed.  And I don't understand how to justify just setting it equal to 1 (which appears to be what the author does).

Am I overlooking something simple here, or do I have some fundamental misunderstanding of what the author is actually doing?  I'm just confused as to the justification of this single operation.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

**Notation note:**

$u_x = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

**EDIT:**
So I decided to pick the problem back up today and just decided to work through my confusion a bit.  I noticed that I end up arriving at the same solution in the end.  The reason being that the $\cos{(\theta)}$ and $\sin{(\theta)}$ for Strauss work out to directly be:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + u_x^2}} \ \ and \ \ \frac{u_x}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2}}$

respectively.  Mine on the other hand, do indeed simplify to that as:

$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 + u_x^2}dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + u_x^2}} \ \ and \ \ \frac{du}{\sqrt{1 + u_x^2}dx} = \frac{u_x}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2}}$

So there really is no problem.  I'm still a bit conceptually confused as to how the author knew to make such a substitution, but I suppose thats fine for now.  I'm updating the post just in case someone else comes across this same issue (unlikely, but possibly still useful to someone!)

Comment: The triangle you describe and the author's are congruent: your sides are $dx, du$ and $\sqrt{1+u_x^2}dx$ wheareas the author's are $1,u_x = du/dx, \sqrt{1+u_x^2}$

Comment: If I remember this correctly, Strauss indeed assumes $\Delta x$ to be constant, which is of course physically unjustified, but the PDE would be much uglier (and nonlinear) without this assumption.

Comment: @J_P Are they congruent?  Or just similar triangles?  It would seem to me that they are not infact congruent, because there is a different scaling (my base is $dx$, his is 1.  Unless I am able to say that $dx$ is 1?

Comment: Yes, sorry, they're similar.

Comment: @JosefE.Greilhuber What do you mean by assuming $\delta x$ to be constant?  I could understand $\delta x$ (or $dx$) being constant, but what he's doing seems quite different, and is saying $dx = 1$, not just that its constant.  Maybe I'm overthinking something or missing something (which is quite possible), but I'm very confused as to how thats a valid thing to do.  I know you say it is not physically justified, but his derivation does end up yielding the correct 1-d wave equation, so it must be valid to some extent.

Comment: @ChrisGnam Sorry for the confusion. What I meant to say was that the derivation from the book works, because there is the assumption of no longitudinal movement. Otherwise, things get nasty (and the string cannot be parametrized by $x$ any longer). But this was not the problem you had, sorry for misreading.